# Optimizing random sampling for scaling permutations

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, optimization

I have a two-fold problem here.
1) My initial problem, which was trying to improve the computational time on my algorithm
2) My next problem, which is one of my 'improvements' appears to consume over 500G RAM memory and I don't really know why.

I've been writing a permutation for a bioinformatics pipeline. Basically, the algorithm starts off sampling 1000 null variants for each variant I have. If a certain condition is not met, the algorithm repeats the sampling with 10000 nulls this time. If the condition is not met again, this up-scales to 100000, and then 1000000 nulls per variant.

I've done everything I can think of to optimize this, and at this point I'm stumped for improvements. I have this gnarly looking comprehension:

```
output_names_df, output_p_values_df = map(list, zip(*[random_sampling_for_variant(variant, options_tables, variant_to_bins, num_permutations, use_num) for variant in variant_list]))
```

Basically all this is doing is calling my random_sampling_for_variants function on each variant in my variant list, and throwing the two outputs from that function into a list of lists (so, I end up with two lists of lists, output_names_df, and output_p_values_df). I then turn these list of lists back into DataFrames, rename the columns, and do whatever I need with them. The function being called looks like:

```
def random_sampling_for_variant(variant, options_tables, variant_to_bins, num_permutations, use_num):
    """
    Inner function to permute_null_variants_single
    equivalent to permutation for 1 variant
    """
    #Get nulls that are in the same bin as our variant
    permuted_null_variant_table = options_tables.get_group(variant_to_bins[variant])
    #If number of permutations > number of nulls, sample with replacement
    if num_permutations >= len(permuted_null_variant_table):
        replace = True
    else:
        replace = False
    #Select rows for permutation, then add as columns to our temporary dfs
    picked_indices = permuted_null_variant_table.sample(n=num_permutations, replace=replace)
    temp_names_df = picked_indices['variant'].values[:use_num]
    temp_p_values_df = picked_indices['GWAS_p_value'].values
    return(temp_names_df, temp_p_values_df)
```

When defining permuted_null_variant_table, I'm just querying a pre-defined grouped up DataFrame to determine the appropriate null table to sample from. I found this to be faster than trying to determine the appropriate nulls to sample from on the fly. The logic that follows in there determines whether I need to sample with or without replacement, and it takes hardly any time at all. Defining picked_indices is where the random sampling is actually being done. temp_names_df and temp_p_values_df get the values that I want out of the null table, and then I send my returns out of the function.

The problem here is that the above doesn't scale very well. For 1000 permutations, the above lines of code take ~254 seconds on 7725 variants. For 10,000 permutations, ~333 seconds. For 100,000 permutations, ~720 seconds. For 1,000,000 permutations, which is the upper boundary I'd like to get to, my process got killed because it was apparently going to take up more RAM than the cluster had.

I'm stumped on how to proceed. I've turned all by ints into 8bit-uint, I've turned all my floats into 16bit-floats. I've dropped columns that I don't need where I don't need them, so I'm only ever sampling from tables with the columns I need. Initially I had the comprehension in the form of a loop, but the computational time on the comprehension is 3/5th that of the loop. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Have you run `line_profiler` or `memory_profiler` on your script?

Comment: After you suggested it, I tried using memory_profiler. The profile returned doesn't match the memory consumption I'm observing while monitoring the cluster using top; memory_profiler reports significantly less. Any idea why?

Comment: Test locally on a smaller sub-problem. `memory_profiler` will not have been written for profiling memory consumption across clusters.